# N Tuple class with size as type information

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm trying to create an N-Tuple in Kotlin, meaning a fixed size Collection/ Array, that has its size as type information. Example:

```
val tuple3 = Tuple<3>(1,2,3) //Type Tuple<3>
val tuple4 = Tuple<4>(4,5,6,7) //Type Tuple<4>

class Tuple<N>() {...}
```

The problem is, that I can't pass a specific number as a generic type (like in typescript or c++ for example). Is there some way to get this to work that I'm not seeing or some kind of workaround, that tells the compiler to treat different sized tuples as different types?

Ranged indexing from 0..N-1 would be nice too:

```
val tuple = Tuple<3>(1,2,3)
tuple[1] //Good
tuple[14] //Error
```

But again, I can't get it to work.

Usecase: I want to implement the Tuple in a Vector class:

```
class Vector<N>(...) : Tuple<N>(...) {...}

val vector3 = Vector(1,2,3)
val vector4 = Vector(4,5,6,7)

vector3 + vector3 //Good
vector3 + vector4 //Error
```

and define arithmetic operations like addtion for the vector.
This is where the type information about the size is important, because it should only be possible to add 2 vectors of the same size. Of course I could just do runtime size checks and throw an error, but a compile time error would be the better solution. And there are other important usecases, where the size of a Tuple/Vector matters at compile time.

The reason I'm not just creating say 8 different subclasses like Tuple1, Tuple2, Tuple3... is because I could need a Tuple/Vector of any size. And just creating a bunch of subclasses is a really ugly solution.

Comment: I think what you're looking for are arrays: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#arrays. You could then do `val x: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, how is it different than arrays/lists if you don't type each item separately? I believe what you try to achieve is impossible. You can create classes `Tuple1`, `Tuple2` and so on, but of course you are then limited to some max size. edit: ahh, ok, I think "fixed size" known at compile time is what differs it from arrays/lists. Again, I don't think this is possible in Java/Kotlin.

Comment: Generally the compiler can't access the generic type because of [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure) (though there are workarounds). I agree with @Augusto, this sounds like an XY Problem. Without using Kotlin or Java specific words can you describe, from a high level, what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think a _wrong_ way (but still ***a*** way) to solve the problem of representing different sized tuples as different types, is to have a `Tuple1<T, TNext>` type. `T` is the type of the element, and `TNext` is either `Tuple0`, or another `Tuple1<...>`. This way, a 3-tuple of int, string, char can be represented as `Tuple1<Int, Tuple1<String, Tuple1<Char, Tuple0>>>`. It would be a pain to access those tuple elements though :)

Comment: @Augusto I don't think this is a XY problem. It sounds like a nice general-purpose addition to the type system. With it you could e.g. create a function that receives an array of exactly 35 integers and it would be enforced by the compiler. Also, bound checks would be unnecessary in such cases. I don't know if (and which) other languages support such feature, but it actually makes sense. Anyway, I don't see any viable workaround to make it available in Kotlin.

Comment: @broot but why on earth would you need exactly 35 integers as a tuple? At that point, just make a (data) class. I agree with Augusto’s comment.

Comment: There's a library called [Tuples4k](https://github.com/fork-handles/forkhandles/tree/trunk/tuples4k) which has up to "Tuple8"... not exactly the same, but it can be used as inspiration to build something similar where each type in the tuple is the same. For what I remember it's limited to 8 as otherwise the size of the classes grows rapidly. I quite like this library to build smallish tuples :D.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll update my question shortly

Comment: @Sweeper You ask me why I prefer to define my function to receive `Tuple35<Int>` instead of just creating a data class with hand-typed 35 properties? ;-) I don't see very good use cases to justify a new feature though. We can have a chessboard game with exactly 8x8 fields. In cryptography and data transforming there are sometimes buffers/keys that are expected to be of exactly e.g. 1024 bytes. But I think in such cases runtime boundary checks are usually enough and compile-time constraints don't add too much.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/breandan/kotlingrad#shape-safety? (found on this page https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-science-overview.html#libraries) What do you think? Also, Checker framework performs compile-time validation, and includes validation of array size https://checkerframework.org/manual/#index-checker - though I suspect it might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @aSemy Thanks, thats basically what I need, although it seems really complicated for what it does. But I'll definitely take a look in the source code